# Read each file inside different directories stored in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, getdirectories

I have to check each xml file inside an array of different directories.

My code(still have errors):

```
string files = "C:\Hello; C:\Hi; D:\Goodmorning; D:\Goodafternoon; E:\Goodevening";
//Get each path and remove whitespaces
string[] paths = files.Split(new[] { ';', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//Use xmlLoc for adding \ to each file
List<string> xmlLoc = new List<string>();
//get the files in directories
string[] getFiles;
//contains the files of each directory
List<string> xmlList

//Add \ each paths variable and store it in xmlLoc list
foreach (string s in paths)
{
     xmlLoc.Add(s + @"\");
}

//get the xml files of each directory in xmlLoc and store it in xmlList
foreach (string file in xmlLoc)
{
     getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(file, "*.xml");
     //the code below lists an error "cannot convert from string[] to string"
     xmlList.Add(getFiles);
}
```

I guess that you cannot store an array in a string list. Is the any other way how I can read the files in each directories stored in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! Just have to add and replace some codes.. :)

```
string files = "C:\Hello; C:\Hi; D:\Goodmorning; D:\Goodafternoon; E:\Goodevening";
//Get each path and remove whitespaces
string[] paths = files.Split(new[] { ';', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//Use xmlLoc for adding \ to each file
List<string> xmlLoc = new List<string>();
//get the files in directories
string[] getFiles;

//Add \ each paths variable and store it in xmlLoc list
foreach (string s in paths)
{
     xmlLoc.Add(s + @"\");
}

//get the xml files of each directory in xmlLoc and loop it to read the files
foreach (string directory in xmlLoc)
{
     getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.xml");
     foreach(string files in getFiles)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(files);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)?

Something like

```
xmlList.AddRange(getFiles);
```

From what I can see, you could have also just gone with something like

```
List<string> xmlList = files.Split(new[] {';', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    SelectMany(p => Directory.GetFiles(p, "*.xml")).
    ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do, but you can use the [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method to add all elements of the `string[]` array returned by `Directory.GetFiles` to your list at once:

```
 string[] getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(file, "*.xml");
 xmlList.AddRange(getFiles);
```

Also consider the following things:

1. Your `xmlList` instance is not initialized, try:`List<string> xmlList = new List<string>`();
2. The name of the variable `file` in the `foreach` construct is a misnomer, consider using `directory` instead, since that is what the "elements" of `xmlLoc` are.
3. You don't really need the `getFiles` variable, a simple    `xmlList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(file, "*.xml"));` would be sufficient in your case.
4. Splitting on whitespace is not a good idea. Directory names (although not the examples you use), may contain whitespace themselves.

Your code looks a little to complicated. AFAICT the following would do the same:

```
string directories = /* ... whatever ... */;
List<string> xmlList = new List<string>();

foreach (string directory in string.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions..RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
   string dir = directory.Trim();

   if (!dir.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparator))
     dir += Path.DirectorySeparator;

   xmlList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.xml"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to initiliaze the XML list, and GetFiles returns an array, so you need to call AddRange, not Add when adding to the XML list.

```
string files = "C:\Hello; C:\Hi; D:\Goodmorning; D:\Goodafternoon; E:\Goodevening";
            //Get each path and remove whitespaces
            string[] paths = files.Split(new[] { ';', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            //Use xmlLoc for adding \ to each file
            List<string> xmlLoc = new List<string>();
            //get the files in directories
            string[] getFiles;
            //contains the files of each directory
            List<string> xmlList = new List<string>();

            //Add \ each paths variable and store it in xmlLoc list
            foreach (string s in paths)
            {
                 xmlLoc.Add(s + @"\");
            }

            //get the xml files of each directory in xmlLoc and store it in xmlList
            foreach (string file in xmlLoc)
            {
                 getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(file, "*.xml");
                 //the code below lists an error "cannot convert from string[] to string"
                 xmlList.AddRange(getFiles);
            }
```